# How to group items in a listView by a value in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview

I have a listView and I want to group items that **share the same ID but different SysDate** so that instead of showing multiple lines with the same value and different dates, I want to show multiple lines only when the ID changes.

***Example:***

From this:

```
ID | Sysdate
1  | 12:00
1  | 12:01
1  | 12:02
2  | 12:03
2  | 12:05
```

To this with only Sysdate changing for the same line:

```
ID | Sysdate
1  | 12:00
2  | 12:05
```

Like if the current item that's been added is the same as the one that already exists in the `listview` then only change the **sysdate** in the same line, if not then add that new line in the `listview`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question as stated is unanswerable.  There exists a concept of "grouping" in Windows `ListView`, (it is for example what you see in Windows Explorer if you open up "My Computer" and select "View" -> "Content",) but I do not think that's what you have in mind.  And besides that concept of "grouping", there is no other defined "grouping" operation that can be performed on a `ListView`.

Your question does not help in defining what you mean by grouping, because for each group of ids (1,2) you have picked a sysdate to display arbitrarily.  (For the case where id=1 you have picked 12:00, which is on the first row with id=1, but in the case where id=2 you have picked 12:05, which is on the second row with id=2.)

I would suggest that you consider grouping a property of your dataset, and not a property of the `ListView`.  In other words, first think exactly what you mean by grouping, then come up with code that performs the grouping on your dataset, and then feed the `ListView` with the grouped dataset.  The `ListView` cannot possibly know anything about your concept of grouping.

Comment: What I mean by grouping is like refresh the line that has the same ID with different sysdate so that the user will only see the sysdate changing of the same ID instead of seeing multiple lines of the same ID with different sysdate thus resulting in a long list of the same ID being repeated. I hope that I'm clear enough, english is not my first language.

Comment: I know what you mean, but a) this is *still* not well defined, and b) try explaining that to the ListView. (Hint: you can't.)

Comment: So is this not possible? I've seen an application where in the listview the ID stays fixed if it's the same but the sysdate is changing and you can see it getting refreshed automatically. Also, when it's a different ID, it creates another line with that ID. And they were using listViews.

Comment: I'm using this for a rfid application that reads tags and displays them in a listview but the problem is that it shows many lines with the same ID and different sysdate resulting in repeated data. The user wants to only see one copy of that ID.

Comment: They are probably doing it in the dataset, and that's precisely what my answer suggests: don't expect the ListView to do your grouping, do the grouping yourself, in your dataset.

Comment: Okay I checked their code and it's a listView that displays that, they're not using a dataset. so there's no solution to this?

Comment: They cannot be "not using a dataset".  Perhaps you don't know what a dataset is.  A dataset is the set of data that you feed to the `ListView`.

Comment: Okay I may have misunderstood what you said, but please bare with me as I'm still a beginner in this and I've seen his code and the items get displayed in a `listView` using `item.SubItems.Add('Value')`

Comment: I suppose you could, if you wanted to, mix your grouping logic with the logic that populates the ListView.  If you do that, then the solution would be fairly simple, but then your question would be tantamount to asking how to code an `if()` statement that refrains from adding a value to a listbox if another value already exists in the listbox.  In any case, if you have access to code that already does that, then why are you asking on stackoverflow?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143307/discussion-between-musicisuniversal-and-mike-nakis).

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = objTest.OrderBy(x => x.ID).GroupBy(x => x.ID).Select(g => new {g, count = g.Count()}).SelectMany(t => t.g.Select(b=>b).Zip(Enumerable.Range(t.count, 1), (j, i) => new {j.Sysdate, j.ID}));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your dataobject has an ID and a sysdate, and thats how you show them, you can't group them. Now if your dataobject has an ID and a List of sysdates, you only get 1 occurance of each ID in your ListView and with each ID you get a List of sysdates. You will have to code your own ViewCell for this.

If you get your dataobjects from a query, you will have to format the dataobjects yourself.